# Rascal MPL how to extract additional loc segments?

Tags: location, rascal

According to [Location](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/), the loc format is `| Uri | ( O, L, < BL, BC > , < EL,EC > )`.

Say we have `loc l = |java+compilationUnit:///test/src/main.java|(0,123,<1,0>,<7,1>);`

How to retrieve e.g. only `< BL, BC >`?

As an aside, how to convert loc values to a string? `toString(l)` does not work.

Comment: You can convert any value `v` to string by inlining it into a string template: `"<v>"` ; this will print locations literally, strings are de-escaped and unquoted and parse trees are yielded to the input sentence they represent.

Comment: Aha! I found that it is even possible to subsequently align converted strings by using nested templates, e.g. `"<center("<v>", 10)>"`.

Comment: Yes, and multiline strings have auto-indentation, so `"   <myFunction(f)>"` will indent all the lines that come out of `myFunciton(f)` with two spaces :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Towards the bottom of [Location](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/), below the list items marked with `**`, there it is:

`l.offset`, `l.length`, `l.begin`, `l.end`. Some useful examples:

- `l.uri` will return `str: "java+compilationUnit:///test/src/main.java"`
- `l.path` will return `str: "/test/src/main.java"`
- `l.begin` will return `tuple[int line,int column]: <1,0>`